# PHP PDO Bind tripping with variable types

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PDO connection (persistent) and I am doing queries like this:

```
$sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE myindex=:PDO_myIndex");
$sql->bindParam(':PDO_myIndex', $myIndex);
$sql->execute();
```

The problem is $myIndex is INT before bindParam (confirmed with var_dump) and then it becomes STRING after bindParam (before the execute).

Is this a normal or known behavior ?

Comment: How is this affecting your application?

Comment: It is the next time I address something to this variable as an INT

Comment: Do you mean the variable `$myIndex` itself converts to string?

Comment: Follow Hanky's answer, and if it's still a string, just cast it as an int like this `$myIndex = (int) $myIndex` or so.

Comment: Yes, it converts itself :) it is solved! thanks Hanky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly specify that using the third parameter available

```
$sql->bindParam(':PDO_myIndex', $myIndex, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                                          ^
```

**[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**

Comment: Great! It works and I need to update entire project now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is an issue, check manual [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#94711).

The third parameter stands for [datatype](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-description) - you can use that one.